# Animation - synchronize lips to wave or MP3

Tags: android, frameworks, animation, character, avatar

I am developing an android application that provides instruction on various topics.  Within my application, I would like to have a "talking head" or even a full-body person that talks with moving lips synchronized (or at least close) to the spoken output.  Ideally, I would want the head/body to move while the speech is occurring also, with eyes blinking, arms (if it has a body) moving, etc. I know how to do all the speech parts, but I've never developed animation before.  I'm using Eclipse.  I really am only looking for advice to get me started down the right path.  Is there a framework, add-on purchase, etc. that will make my life easier?  There has to be a better method than animating/rotating open/close mouth images during the speech output.  I do NOT want jib-jab type of animation!  Thank you in advance for any starting advice you can give me!

Answer (score 1):

[`Xface`](http://xface.fbk.eu/) may be a solution. You need SMIL scripts for the audio.

Comment: I wish I was smart enough to know how to port this over!  I can't even find the API documented anywhere.